# create get method on onclick method

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I would like to get information about customers when someone click on 'option' element in 'select' using Thymeleaf and Spring:

```
<select th:onclick="javascript:doAction(' + @{/userInfo} + '?name=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value' + ')">
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
</select>
```

REQUESTED QUERY :

> http://server:port/userInfo?name=John

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userInfo", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String processForm(String name) {
  System.out.print(user); // "John"
}
```

but it is not working. :(

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: what does it mean not working? :) can you see HTTP request in your browser?

Comment: yes, exactly :-( nothings happen. I am not sure, if statement "javascript:doAction" is correct, because nothing has happened after I click to 'option' in 'select', you know if some trigger was started.

Comment: I am not expert on thymeleaf, but what HTML/JS code was generated on client? do you see any problems in JS console?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have an issue with this part :

```
th:onclick="javascript:doAction(' + @{/userInfo} + ' name=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value' + ')"
```

Did you check what Thymeleaf generated ?

**However**. Here's an idea on how you could do with some jQuery to trigger a request each time the selection change :

```js
$('#users').on('change', function(){
    var url = $(this).data('url') + "?name=" + $('#users option:selected').val();
    $('#result').html(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="users" data-url="/userInfo">
    <option value="John">John</option>
    <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
</select>

<p id="result"></p>
```

In this snippet, I'm just printing the URL you suggest in your post, but you got the idea. And with Thymeleaf you would replace `data-url="/userInfo"` by `th:attr="data-url=@{/userInfo}"`

Also, you could have a problem with your method `processForm(String name)`.
Variable `name` is a request parameter, so you need to **annotate** it, e.g. :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userInfo", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String processForm(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name) {
    System.out.print(user); // "John"
}
```